# How do I assign a method to a variable in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");

let button = document.createElement('button');
let a  = greeter.greet;
button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(greeter.greet());//works
    alert(a());//doesn't work
}
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

I'd like to store a class method in a variable, and then call it. How can I make this example work? It works if I store just "greeter" in "a", and then call greet, but I don't want to do it like that. I'm trying it on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

```
let a  = greeter.greet.bind(greeter);
```

**Actual explanation**:

This actually doesn't have anything to do with TypeScript *specifically*, but with JavaScript and how `this` works.

When you assigned `greeter.greet()` to `a`, what you actually did was assign `Greeter`'s class method `greet()` to `a`, instead of the `greet()` method of the `Greeter` class instance which you named `greeter`. Therefore, by `bind()`-ing `greeter` to the `Greeter#greet()` function, you assign `greeter`'s `greet()` method to `a`.

For further reading:

1. [MDN article which explains `this` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), specifically "The `bind` method" section
2. [TypeScript Wiki article about `this` in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript)

Comment: How can I do this automatically? I have a function that is supposed to take methods as arguments, so is there a way to "auto bind"? Because I have a function like this: function takemethod(let method)

Comment: Why not just pass the function already bound to the instance when calling `takemethod`? Or pass the instance as a second argument and bind to it inside the function.

Comment: So it's not possible? It's because I wanted to avoid extra arguments. Normally in javascript you can just assign functions. Like, "a = console.log; a("something")" works, so I expected it to work the same in typescript. But I see it has to do with this bind thing, I'll read about it.

Comment: For your convenience I just added a couple of links that'll be useful for you.